# Bitbucket in HTTPS : git push outputs an fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: authentication, https, push, bitbucket

I have a problem with bitbucket and git in HTTPS.

When I try a push I have the following output :

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: Authentication failed

$ git push
fatal: Authentication failed
```

.git/config is configured with the HTTPS link I found on the repo on Bitcucket.

The pull works however perfectly with this HTTPS link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a problem of rights on bitbucket, not a problem of config.

I was on read only.
The admin added to me the right to write and the push is now working.